# geth node stuck on "Looking for peers"

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum

I'm new to blockchain and trying two create two nodes and execute a transaction using geth. However, when I try to run the geth --mine command, it keeps of printing "Looking for Peers". Can someone please help?

geth account new --datadir node1
geth account new --datadir node2

geth init mynetwork.json --datadir node1
geth init mynetwork.json --datadir node2

geth --datadir node1 --mine --miner.threads 1
geth --datadir node2 --port 30304 --rpc --bootnodes "enode://@127.0.0.1:30303"

Comment: This question is not about programming, so it is better suited for https://ethereum.stackexchange.com